# Azure Data Explorer Syslog virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

sorry for the basic question but I am totally new to this technology and would like to ask some questions to all of you expert and amazing people.

I have a windows virtual machine that receives a lot of syslogs on port 3014. So far I have been using Elasticsearch, logstash and Grafana to collect those data and visualise them.

But I would like to take a different approach and move everything directly to azure portal, so I came across azure data explorer.

Can any one direct me a good documentation (because I couldn't find any) how to send directly those syslogs from my vm to data explorer to analyse them and visualise them?

Please if my request is not 100% clear, just ask for more details.

Thank you very much for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

The solution you need has two parts: 1. Listening on the syslog port (3014) and 2. pushing the data to Azure Data Explorer (Kusto)

You need a component that has the syslog listening capability and the output to Azure Data Explorer.

You can definitely continue to use **Logstash** and leverage the Logstash Azure Data Explorer plugin (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-logstash) to send the data.
But you can also use a **Telegraf** agent with the Azure Data Explorer output plugin (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-explorer-blog/new-azure-data-explorer-output-plugin-for-telegraf-enables-sql/ba-p/2829444) or **FluentBit** (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/fluent-bit-connector-for-azure-storage-to-support-azure-data-explorer/)

You can also add another hop and leverage Azure Event Hub to aggregate the data. Most syslog listeners can send data to event hubs via the Kafka head it exposes. Then Azure Data Explorer can listen on the Event Hub.